# How to call showNormal out from SLOT in main function?

Tags: c++, qt

I've got

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QObject* root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);

QAction *restoreAction = new QAction(QObject::tr("&Restore"), root);
root->connect(restoreAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), root, SLOT(showNormal()));
```

in main body and it works. However I want to call `showNormal` also there but not in slot and I can find where from it comes and how does it even work?

finally I'm trying to show my window on clicking tray icon

```
root->connect(trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::activated,
              [root] (QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason) {
  switch (reason) {
  case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
  case QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick:
    ((QWidget*)root)->showNormal();
```

so far it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe `root->showNormal();`?

Comment: @vahancho 'showNormal' : is not a member of 'QObject'

Comment: cast `root` to `QQuickWindow` and call `root->showNormal();`

Comment: @Meefte thanks! may you post it as answer or should I close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `root` to `QQuickWindow`

```
QQuickWindow *root = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
root->showNormal();
```

Comment: I worth to check the `root` pointer after casting. It can be 0. Also, `rootObjects()` can return an empty list.